# Changing the value of an input from another input on keyup using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, function, user-input

I have two inputs set up to simultaneously convert lbs to kgs and kgs to lbs on keyup depending on which input you use. I also have an error function to run if the input is not a number. My conversion works well for both inputs on keyup and the error as well, initially, but if I clear the inputs or switch from one to another , I lose the error function and the clear function doesn't clear the input completely in the second one, it leaves a number, 0.00. I am using a jquery plugin, jquery number to round the numbers to two places.

Here is a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/macsupport/v15on8t3/) and my code:

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
 var kg = 0.453
 $('#weight_lb').on('keyup', function () {
    var wtvalueL = parseFloat($('#weight_lb').val());
    if (!isNaN(wtvalueL)) {
        $("#weight_kg").val($("#weight_lb").val() * kg).number(true, 2);
    } else { // the input wasn't a number
        $('#weight_lb').val('');
        $(".wt_error").fadeIn();
        setTimeout(function () {
            $(".wt_error").fadeOut();
        }, 2000);
        return false;
    }
 });
 $('#weight_kg').on('keyup', function () {
    var wtvalueK = parseFloat($('#weight_kg').val());
    if (!isNaN(wtvalueK)) {
        $("#weight_lb").val($("#weight_kg").val() / kg).number(true, 2);
    } else { // the input wasn't a number
        $('#weight_kg').val('');
        $(".wt_error").fadeIn();
        setTimeout(function () {
            $(".wt_error").fadeOut();
        }, 2000);
        return false;
    }
});
$(".clear").on('click', function () {
    $("#weight_lb").val("").attr('placeholder', 'Enter Weight');
    $("#weight_kg").val("").attr('placeholder', 'Enter Weight');
});
});
```

Comment: use the input event instead of keyup

Comment: Thanks. Tried it but I lose my error function in the opposite input after using the first input and clear still gives me a 0.00